# My IP gets blocked for odd reasons by my server each time i do ajax continuous update

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Everytme when i call ajax and i use timeout to repeat the ajax function, after a few minutes, i can't have access to my website, it;s like my IP address gets blocked from my server, by the way i am using 000webhost for hosting my server. The code is below .Can someone assist me and tell me what i can do solve this problem without telling me to use websockets/comets, i want to use AJAX for very frequent update maybe up to 10 seconds. Not a most but it will be great if someone can show  solutions without the use use of JQuery Thank you.

```
function display_message(user,id){

    var xhr;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
/**********************************************************/

var data = "user="+user+"&id="+id;


     xhr.open("POST", "message_read.php", true); 

     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                  
     xhr.send(data);
     xhr.onreadystatechange = display_data;
    function display_data() {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {

     document.getElementById("message_box").innerHTML =xhr.responseText;
      mymessage =setTimeout(display_message(user,id), 5000);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');

      }
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to ask server owner about restrictions.

Comment: Do you think it's the servers side? how can i fix the problem?

Comment: ask server owner about restriction :) it will be fastest way, if not, try to execute script with lower time interval